# Putting a class inside another list in another class

Tags: java, class, arraylist, intellij-idea, java-8

so basically i want to put the class "GradeBook", which contains 2 arraylists, inside another class "course". I create a setCourse method to link both class together but when I tried to put in the GradeBook inside a list "gradebooks" inside "course" class, there's a NullPointerException. Why can't I put this class i the list.

public class GradeBook {

```
 private List<Double> assignmentScores;
 private List<Double> quizScores;
 private Course course;

 public GradeBook() {
    assignmentScores = new ArrayList<>();
    quizScores = new ArrayList<>();
 }
 public void setCourse(Course course) {
    this.course = course;
 }

public class Course {

private List<GradeBook> gradeBooks;

public void addGradebook(GradeBook gradebook) {
    gradebook.setCourse(this);
    gradeBooks.add(gradebook);
}
```

Comment: because `gradeBooks` is `null`. That’s what a `NullPointerException` tells you. By looking at the stack trace, you see where it happened, which provides you a hint about what could have been `null`.

Comment: I was waiting for that hammer down on the duplicate.

Comment: Can you post the complete code?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `gradeBooks`. You are getting the null pointer because gradeBooks is null when you try to add a grade book. As an example, you could initialize it in a constructor of the `Course` class.

```
public Course() {
    gradeBooks = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addGradebook(GradeBook gradebook) {
    gradebook.setCourse(this);
    gradeBooks.add(gradebook);
}
```